# MySQL - Same row allotted two users

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a task queue project which will be used by several employees in my organization. We are in testing phase and around 10 users are testing on it.

I have task table. In this task table there 1000+ records.

Structure of tasks table is:

```
id  task_details category_id    status
```

Each user is allotted a task and saved in the sub table called user_tasks.

Structure of user_tasks table is:

```
id  task_id     user_id    status
```

Structure of users table is:

```
id  user_name  Email  status
```

A task can not be allotted to two users at the same time. But, I am intermittently facing issues of 1 task row is allotted to two different users in  user_tasks table.

My query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM tasks t 
WHERE 
    t.status="Pending"
    AND t.category_id=1
    AND t.id NOT IN (SELECT task_id FROM user_tasks ut WHERE ut.task_id=t.id and ut.status='Inprogress')
LIMIT 1
```

And if the query returns a record it is saved in user_tasks table.

Can some one help me finding and resolving the issue?

I am using Mysql and Php

Thanks

Comment: Is the task_id in user_tasks set to UNIQUE?

Comment: The issue is most likely to be in he code that stores the tasks agianst a user. You either have to manually check the new row is not a dup before inserting it or set a unique index on `task_id and user_id` in the  `user_tasks` table

Comment: I cant set a unique index on `task_id` and `user_id` because a task will again be in pending state after a few time/day and may be allotted to a different user.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry I never get tired of that link.  Can you imagine a day when you don't have to post it anymore?

Comment: @mickmackusa Perhaps when something fundamental changes in SO's questions submission protocol - but I ain't holding out much hope.

Comment: @sas what kinds of `status` values are there?

Comment: @mickmackusa status values are `Pending` , `Inprogress` and `Complete`

Comment: You are not checking for task id in your query. They query could return many rows!

Comment: Can you explain in greater detail the issue?  There are two users assigned to a single task when status is what?  Can't the status be used to determine if a new user is welcome to the assignment?  When a user is no longer assigned to a task, do you want to keep the record or can you overwrite it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, add an index to your user_tasks table to avoid duplicates.

```
ALTER TABLE `temp`.`user_tasks` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `uq_user_task` (`task_id` ASC, `user_id` ASC);
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment that the same table will be used for re-assigning the task to some other user, I'd insert records into that table using the following query...

```
INSERT INTO user_tasks (task_id, user_id, `status`)
SELECT id, :user_id, 'Inprogress'
FROM tasks t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_tasks WHERE task_id = t.id AND `status` = 'Inprogress')
AND t.category_id = 1 AND t.`status` = 'Pending'
LIMIT 1;
```

This will insert tasks that are category 1 and pending in status, and only if there isn't an open user_task record (status = 'Inprogress').

To further add other users, you'd need to first set the 'Inprogress' to 'Done' or 'Escalated' or something.

I'd also add a date column to track when a status was assigned to a particular user.

Comment: I have added structure of my users table. The query that I put in my question is used to check for Pending task and save it in the user_tasks table.

Comment: @sas How do you know which user is available? Do you look at the status column?

Comment: The logged in user. When a logged in user pick a task the query runs, get a pending task and save it in the user_tasks table.